# how to add strings in text file to datagridview?

Tags: c#

I have a text file that has values on each line and each value is separated by a comma.I want to add the first line of data in the first row of datagrid view and each value in first line separated with comma to be added in different columns of that row and second line of data in second row

[image: data file]

I didn't know the actual code so I roughly tried this code:

```
string FilePath = Application.StartupPath + "\\Items.txt";
string[] Records = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath);
for (int i = 0; i < Records.Length; i++)
{
    //listView1.Items.Add(Records[i],Records[i+1],Records[i+2]);
    DGMenu.Rows.Add(Records[i]);
}
```

Comment: so every comma is a new line?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q&A site, and one thing most good question have in common is the question mark. I don't see a question in yours. Please edit your post by making it a real and specific question.

Comment: You might want to search for a CSV Parser and use that to process your file (assuming it is a valid CSV file which it looks to be form the data you've provided).

Comment: What actually happens when your code runs?  Are you using Win Forms?  I set a simple test Win Form app with a DataGridView and it doesn't seem to be possible to add a row in this way without adding columns first.  It's not clear what you are trying to do here...  If you are adding columns manually assuming that there will always be 3 entries per line then this isn't the most robust approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Records.Split(",")  should give you what you need if I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split each row with `','` and add that into `DGMenu` rows

```
for (int i = 0; i < Records.Length; i++)
{      
   DGMenu.Rows.Add(i.Split(','));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the answers so far have answered the OP's question as it was asked.  However, I feel someone should point out that this isn't the most robust way to achieve the goal.

There appears to be an assumption that there will only be 3 entries per line.  Maybe this is guaranteed, maybe it isn't?  It's unclear from the question.

I'm assuming that somewhere in the example columns have been set up either in design time or in code...?  Again it's unclear but I'm fairly certain you can't add rows in this way until columns exist.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

A better way (depending on whether or not this is product code or just some test app) is to do as Chris suggests and use some kind of parsing mechanism that provides a collection of instances of a type that can be data bound to the grid.

It looks like some of the info in the text file is a currency?  Proper parsing and data binding would allow this information to be displayed as currency...

I could be barking up the wrong tree but I felt it should be mentioned.